# I have a background-image in css file but don't show in site.how to fix this prblm. i sent screenshot. thx

Tags: php, images, css, html5, bloginfo

[image][image]

lock at the pic dont show the background-image.
i try this but not working....  background-image: url("/assets/Logo.png");

how can i fix this prblm. plz give me the solution. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Shift+I to open the developer's tool bar and examine your #hero to check if the image URL is correct.

Will be helpfull if you share the full path of the image.

Comment: I have salved my problem now.  the problem had an in CSS file.
just I change the attributes :

background-image: url("assets/img/hero-bg.jpg");
background-position: top center;

and now show the image. i spend for this thing almost  6 hours. oh my  god.

Comment: but I dont know why this attribute ( background-image: url("assets/img/hero-bg.jpg")  top center;) not worked in wp but work after change.

Comment: "background-image" is only for the image.

Use "background-position" for the position o just "background" for both things.